# specialized solver for linear 1st order ODEs sytem with time-dependent coeffients problem

Tags: ode

I need to solve many times the following ODEs system:

```
F'(t) = A(t)*F(t) + B(t)*U(t)
F(0) = F0
```

where matrices A(t), B(t) and vector control function U(t) contains time-dependent coefficients or functions, which are represented in my case by discrete time-series (fixed sampling period ~ 1sec, 1e3-1e5 samples). Typical dimension of problem is ~ 2 - 6.

Proper interpolation (smooth and fast enough) of discrete time-series is the crucial requirement.

This ODEs systems will be solved many times (~ 1e2-1e4 times) for different A(t),B(t), U(t) and F0, so solver should be fast enough + parallelizеd (multithreaded).

There are available a plenty of generic ODE solvers, but I am looking for a specific problem solver (linear 1st order ODEs system with time-dependent coefficients), which will be fast and reliable.

I prefer MATLAB, but of course, any other solution (Python, Julia, C/C++, ...) will be very helpful.

My questions are:

1. Is there any other special solver suitable to solve my specific problem effectively and reliably?
2. Is there any reason to expect, that some special solver would be better than standard generic ODE solvers in my specific problem?
3. Is there any suitable or recommended strategy how to solve this specific problem?